# Save changes popup is still appearing despite .Close savechanges:=False

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the following code to close a workbook that is temporarily created in order to add a table to an email message but the save changes popup still appears when I run the macro.

is there another way of ensuring that there is no popup during the execution of this function?

```
Function RangetoHTML(Rng As Range)
 Dim fso As Object
 Dim ts As Object
 Dim TempFile As String
 Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
 Rng.Copy
 Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
 With TempWB.Sheets(1)
 .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
 .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
 .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
 .Cells(1).Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 On Error Resume Next
 .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
 .DrawingObjects.Delete
 On Error GoTo 0
 End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
 With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
 SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
 Filename:=TempFile, _
 Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
 Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
 HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
 .Publish (True)
 End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
 RangetoHTML = ts.readall
 ts.Close
 RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
 "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
 With TempWB
.Close savechanges:=False
 End With

'Delete the htm file used in this function
 Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
 Set fso = Nothing
 Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Try putting the saving code line between `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.

Comment: This worked! wow thanks for that, I was not sure why it worked in one of spreadsheet but not the other

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: If you are deleting or killing the tempfile then save the changes...